# SQL show duplicates after join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

I'm trying to select all duplicated (removing the distinct record) entry of a table, result of a join.

I'm trying to do it with:

```
SELECT items.id, b.title FROM b WHERE b.title IN (
SELECT b.title FROM b LIMIT 20 GROUP BY b.title HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) INNER JOIN items USING (number)
```

Note: `number` is a Index common to 'items' and 'b' tables used for the join.

But obvious that doesn't work. I'm trying to understand how to get the duplicates and return the join result.

An example of output should be:

```
 id | title
----|----
001 | House
002 | House
005 | Tree
010 | Tree
006 | Car
007 | Car
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Why that LIMIT?

Comment: MySql and the LIMIT is there only for debugging, 20 is a good number to get some duplicates for testing

Comment: Your query should not even parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `COUNT(*)` in a subquery incurs overhead.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT i.id, b.title
FROM b JOIN
     items i
     USING (number)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM b b2
              WHERE b2.title = b.title AND b2.id <> b.id
             );
```

This does assume assume that `b` has a unique id on each row, which is used in the subquery.  This query can make use of an index on `b(title, id)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first part was clear, had a bit of difficult to understand the second part. That explained very well how to select the right elements

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM b INNER JOIN items USING number
WHERE title IN 
    (SELECT title
     FROM b
     GROUP BY title
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished something similar a few times using a query similar to this.

```
SELECT id
       ,title
  FROM some_table AS T1
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM some_table AS T2
         WHERE T1.title = T2.title) > 1
```